# Postgres, insert into array type filed in Node app

Tags: node.js, arrays, postgresql

I am trying to do a insert into a table that has an field array of type integer.

I'm using node-postgres and node-pg-format package to do query. Syntax for insert to that kind of field is:

```
INSERT INTO table(field) VALUES(ARRAY [1,2])
```

But I don't see a way to generate this syntax using any package to the Postgres database in a node. I also need to make multi insert so final query should looks like

```
INSERT INTO table(field) VALUES(ARRAY [1,2]), (ARRAY [3,4])
```

I tried use pg-format like that:

```
const params = ['a', 1, [1,2]];
const query = format(`INSERT INTO table(field1, field2, fieldArray) %L`, params);

Result: 
INSERT INTO table(field1, field2, fieldArray) VALUES('a', 1, 1, 2);

const params = ["a", 1, 'ARRAY [1,2]'];
const query = format(`INSERT INTO table(field1, field2, fieldArray) %L`, params);

Result: 
INSERT INTO table(field1, field2, fieldArray) VALUES("a", 1, "ARRAY [1,2]");
```

Is any way to do this?

Comment: `VALUES("a", 1, 1, 2);` - those double quotes are wrong. String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL.

Comment: I don't know Node.js, but you could try to create a string array literal, `'{1,2}'` instead of `array[1,2]`

Comment: I edited the double quotes. Of course  in the real code  was correct.

Using '{1,2}' insted array[1,2] solve problem with building query.

const params = ["a", 1, ' {1,2}'];

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did use pg-format to form queries and then pg to query for data

```
const insertInto = format(
    `
    INSERT INTO blog_posts
    (title, author, body, post_banner, tags)
    VALUES
    (
      %L, ARRAY[%L]
    )
    RETURNING post_id, title, author, body, tags, post_banner, created_at;
  `,
    [blogPost.title, blogPost.author, blogPost.body, blogPost.post_banner],
    blogPost.tags
  );

  const post = await db.query(insertInto);
```

It works but using format for user inputs is probably bad, I'm not sure if it sanitizing against SQL Injection. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: To confirm, you're using the `pg-format` package for format()? If so, docs state in very first line: 
Node.js implementation of PostgreSQL format() to safely create dynamic SQL queries. SQL identifiers and literals are escaped to help prevent SQL injection. The behavior is equivalent to PostgreSQL format(). This module also supports Node buffers, arrays, and objects which is explained below.

should be good.